# NumPy error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() when not using Boolean logic

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to convert a 2d NumPy array of complex numbers into another 2d array RGB values for an image, by mapping a function over the array.

This is the function:

```
import numpy as np
import colorsys

def ComplexToRGB(complex):
    angle = ((np.angle(complex,deg=True)+360)%360)/360
    magnitude = np.absolute(complex)
    rawColor =  colorsys.hls_to_rgb(angle,0.5,1-np.log2(magnitude)%1)
    return rawColor
```

I map this function over an array by passing the array as input:

```
print(ComplexToRGB(foo))
```

where `foo` is `foo=np.linspace(-1-1j,1+1j,11)`.

When I pass a single complex number as an input, I don't get an error, but when I try to use an array as an input, I get the rather mysterious error

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

  File "C:\Users\trevo\Documents\GitHub\NumPy-Complex-Function-Grapher\colorTest.py", line 7, in ComplexToRGB
    rawColor =  colorsys.hls_to_rgb(angle,0.5,1-np.log2(magnitude)%1)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\Documents\GitHub\NumPy-Complex-Function-Grapher\colorTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(ComplexToRGB(foo))
```

I understand that you can't use Boolean conditionals when you map over an array, but I don't have any logic in my function, just math, so I'm not user where the error is coming from.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Full traceback please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single complex number:

```
In [3]: ComplexToRGB(1+3j)
Out[3]: (0.6041685072417726, 0.6695179762781593, 0.33048202372184066)
```

same thing with a single element array:

```
In [4]: ComplexToRGB(np.array(1+3j))
Out[4]: (0.6041685072417726, 0.6695179762781593, 0.33048202372184066)
In [5]: ComplexToRGB(np.array([1+3j]))
Out[5]: (array([0.60416851]), array([0.66951798]), array([0.33048202]))
```

but with a 2 element array:

```
In [6]: ComplexToRGB(np.array([1+3j]*2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-a1b8e92d5dcc>", line 1, in <module>
    ComplexToRGB(np.array([1+3j]*2))
  File "<ipython-input-1-05948df7c0bd>", line 6, in ComplexToRGB
    rawColor =  colorsys.hls_to_rgb(angle,0.5,1-np.log2(magnitude)%1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/colorsys.py", line 99, in hls_to_rgb
    if s == 0.0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

You may not have any explicit logic in your code, but the Python `colorsys` code does do a `if` test.  `colorsys` is a base Python module, and is not written with `numpy` arrays in mind.

Read the full traceback, and if necessary, read the docs of the relevant function(s).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  Is there anything I can do to be to use it as it is, or would I have use the slower NumPy.vectorize(), or write my own color conversion?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is just a convenience, a list comprehension is just as good.  I don't know know enough about this `colorsys` conversion to help with alternatives.  I suppose a start would be to look at its code to see just what it is doing with the `if` test.